# How to go about converting a font to an actual link to use inside HTML doc

Tags: css, fonts, hyperlink

so I have the WOFF file provided but was wondering how does google create links like this?  I basically have a custom font that my company wants me to use for an email but I need to create the link.  Is there a special process?

Thanks alot!

Comment: you use the `@font-face` CSS syntax to define your custom font (the path to the WOFF file and the font-family name), then you can use that font-family name in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks zgood - so I would have to host this file somewhere on a server along with the stylesheet?  I have the WOFF file in a zip file currently

Comment: Yes. Typically I will have a folder called fonts where I keep my font files (.woff, .woff2, .ttf, etc.) then I create a `fonts.css` file (just for organizational purposes) that has nothing but `@font-face` definitions that link fonts in my font folder to a `font-family` name (i.e `font-family: "MyCustomFontName";`). Then I just import my `fonts.css` before my main stylesheet(s) and I can use that font-family in my styles (i.e. `body { font-family: "MyCustomFontName", Arial, sans-serif; }`).